# jquery detecting the click event

Tags: jquery, onclick

```
<?php
while($i<10){
    $roll_no++;?>
    <h4 onclick='alert("Roll No.=$roll_no")'><? echo ucwords($name);?></h4><div>
    <table class='accor'>
        <tr><td>Roll No.</td><td>: <? echo $roll_no;?></td></tr>
    </table></div>"
<?
    $i++;
}?>
```

this is my code and from code all are nearly clear.
i'm not using any id or class as if the `$i` goes up to 100, with all the dynamic ids created, it'll be dificult to handle i guess.

how can i show the alert with the proper roll no. under each h4 clicked. like

```
**Jack**
Roll No.: 125

**Jill**
Roll No.: 127
```

when the user clicks on jack alert will show 125 and when he clicks on jill the alert will show 127

Comment: It is already doing what you want? And how is this related with jquery?

Comment: @Zim84 He want aproache it with jquery.

Comment: no he does not do it right even with PHP

Comment: actually i'm using jquery ui dialog, and i'm trying to use the roll_no inside the javascript document ready function.

Comment: i've not used php there. i just showed what i want to show there. or u may say i want to show the text of the td under each h4 inside the alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using jquery's events :

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6fa7X/)

```
<?php
while($i<10){
    $roll_no++;?>
    <h4  class="clickMe" data-name="<?php echo $name;?>" data-rollno="<?php echo $roll_no?>"><? echo ucwords($name);?></h4><div>
    <table class='accor'>
        <tr><td>Roll No.</td><td>: <? echo $roll_no;?></td></tr>
    </table></div>"
<?
     $i++;
}?>
```

Script :

```
$('.clickMe').click(function(e){
    var $obj = $(e.target);
    var name = $obj.data('name');
    var rollno = $obj.data('rollno');
    alert(name+"\n\nRoll No : "+rollno);
});
```

Cheers

Comment: thanks man... with little modification, it does exactly what i want.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$roll_no = 0;
$i = 0;
while($i<10){
    $roll_no++;
?>
    <h4 onclick="javascript:alert('Roll No.=<?php echo $roll_no;?>')"><?php echo ucwords($name);?></h4>
<?php
    $i++;
}?>
```

Comment: +1 I was wondering why does one need jQuery for it and was gonna put just this